# Check the license in the constructor

Tags: c++, copy-protection

I need to protect a C++ library that I am writing. The library has a single entry point via class called `foo`. What I did is:

```
//.hpp
class foo{
public:
foo();
....
}

//.cpp
foo::foo(){
    if(check_for_lic()==result::failed){
        throw no_lic_exception();
    }
}
```

The class only has one constructor.

My question is this enough? In other words, without any reverse engineering, is it possible for a developer to construct `foo` without checking the license?

P.S. I will distribute **headers** and a static library **.lib** (or **.a**)

Comment: Why one would not RE it and remove the check, if he would decide to avoid your "copy protection"? And as your implementation is the most trivial one, it's IMO not worth it (although depends who is your target audience and market, even trivial protection in extreme cases may help, but in general copy protection will just annoy paying customers, not thieves) (or you need to be very clever and experienced to annoy both customers and thieves, but then protection development time may easily take month+)

Comment: Very bad idea. Don't harass your users. Companies that want to use your software legally will pay you. People who can't or won't pay you are either going to bypass your licensing code, or go use your competitors software.

Comment: your solution is easy to debug/patch. you cannot revoke it if it is running and also someone could write a service for multiple users. Do a threat analysis and then decide whether it is worth the effort. read about commercial product features to get an idea.

Answer (score 3):

If he has the header file, he can simply add another, overloaded   constructor for foo, that doesn't check the license, and use that.

Comment: If I'd use the _Pimpl Idiom_, would that be enough to protect?

Comment: You could use your constructor code (which is not in the header) to create an invariant (such as a hash), then that can be checked by later code.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing how the class is intended to be used. But I would say that purely software methods of "protection" are normally very easily by-passed, and are quite likely to harm sales of your product.

Comment: Thank you, but it would be useless since there is important code in the constructor that the class would be useless without it